# insert image in renderDataTable for shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Here's the directory structure:

> ```
> app.R
> www/Belgium.png
> ```

and the code in `app.R`:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(shinydashboard)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(DT::dataTableOutput("test")),
      dashboardBody()
    )

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      dat <- data.frame(
        country = c('China', 'Belgium'),
        flag = c('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52"></img>',
                 '<img src="Belgium.png" height="52"></img>'
        )
      )
      output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({ DT::datatable(dat, escape = F) })
    })

    app <- shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)

    app
```

As you can see in the result, the first image (flag of China taken from the web) is well represented but the second image (flag of Belgium hosted on my local file system under `www/`) is not shown.  [image]

I've been pulling my hair trying to understand what is going on but no luck so far...  Why is shiny not able to see the picture on my local file system?

Comment: As per your initial directory structure, the file is in `www` folder

Comment: Yes, I've tried to put it in the same root directory as app.R also but it didn't work.  Everything I've seen is about putting it www/ so that's what I did...

Are you able to reproduce the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

By creating a folder 'www' and placing the 'Belgium.jpg' in it is working.

[image]

Getting the output

[image]

Comment: Well, not me...  I've tried both on MacOS and Ubuntu.  Same result.  Can it be related to the way it is run?  I tried executing the code both from RStudio and from command line Rscript and still got the same result.

Comment: @ranlot I am using the RunApp.  BTW, it is in windows.  I had the same issue while placing the figure at the same directory.  Then, I created the www and it is working for me

Comment: from the Rstudio?

Comment: @ranlot yes, it is from the Rstudio

Comment: How would you run it externally without RStudio?  Let's say from command line and what would it mean code-wise?

Comment: Could you please try or point me to a good example of how to run Shiny app without Rstudio?  It's driving me crazy as I know that the code must be right...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157095/discussion-between-ranlot-and-akrun).

Comment: @ranlot you can check [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/Gx2P_dhzM38)